# java: find a class with main method automatically

Tags: java, javac

Is there a way to tell jvm to look for a class with entry `main` method automatically rather than to specify it when invoking `java ClassWithMainMethod`?

In other words, I have directory with many compiled classes one of which has `main` method and I want to only specify that directory.

Comment: Where would the JVM look for such a class?

Comment: What if several classes in the directory have `main` methods?

Comment: Java doesn't do this out of the box, because it's not very common for the main class of a Java program to be in the directory you have to launch the java process in – having classes in the "default" package is considered bad practice. In fact, it's not even common for a java program to just have `.class` files in a directory – you usually distribute a bunch of `.jar` files with your application and  required libraries and execute one of those, or provide a launcher script to have more control over startup.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer In my scenario than it would be ok if any one is invoked.

Comment: You could write a program to search for the Main method inside your software, and then write the MANIFEST file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. You can create an executable jar, and define what the main class is in the jar manifest, allowing you to use

```
java -jar MyJar.jar
```

though.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

You may also deliver your app with a script which executes the appropriate command for you:

```
#startup.cmd
java -cp ... com.foo.bar.Main
```

Answer (score 7):

If, in your scenario:

- it is okay to execute the first classfile in a directory;
- the classes in this directory are in the default package;
- the `javap` command is available – i.e. you've got a JDK installed, not just a JRE;

you could use the following bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
for classfile in *.class; do
    classname=$(echo $classfile | cut -f 1 -d '.')
    echo $classname
    if javap -public $classname | fgrep 'public static void main(java.lang.String[])'; then
        java $classname "$@"
    fi
done
```

Comment: This is the actual way to go, but please note that the `main` function can also be decorated with a `final` keyword that your grep call will miss. Also, depending on whether the author wrote `main(String... args)` or `main(String[] args)`, signature will be different. You have to rely on the line just below to overcome this other issue.
You can see how we dealt with that in our [camisole sandbox project](https://github.com/prologin/camisole/blob/master/camisole/languages/java.py).

Answer (score 0):

If your application is inside a .jar file, you can specify the main class in its manifest

Answer (score 0):

If there are more then one class with main method?

I think you can create a  executable Jar file and specify class having main function in manifest file. So, whenever user will run jar file. Class with main function will be executed.